# Subjonctif ou conditionnel

Tags: subjonctif, conditionnel

1.Je cherche un hôtel où les chiens **soient** acceptés. Je cherche un hôtel où les chiens **seraient** acceptés.

les deux sont possibles? si oui, quelle est la différence?

2.La première fois **que** je l'ai rencontré, je ne l'ai pas trouvé sympathique. // La première fois **où** je l'ai rencontré, je ne l'ai pas trouvé sympathique.

---

J'ai entendu dire la première est utilisée plus souvent, alors, on doit mémoriser quand on utilise le pronom relatif 'que' pour le temps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Je dirais :

> Je cherche un hôtel où les chiens **sont** acceptés.

On peut dire aussi

> Je cherche un hôtel où les chiens **seraient** acceptés.

Ça sous-entend que c'est rare, qu'il est probable que tu n'en trouves pas.

La première option doit aussi être correcte, mais beaucoup plus rare. Je ne suis pas sûr qu'elle soit incorrecte mais je ne l'utiliserais pas.

2. La version avec "*que*" est correcte.

> *La première fois où je l'ai rencontré, je ne l'ai pas trouvé sympathique.*

Est incorrecte mais parfois utilisée dans le langage courant. L'erreur vient sûrement de la construction assez proche :

> La fois où tu n'as pas pu venir, il pleuvait et j'ai dû rentrer à pied.

On parle d'un évènement qui s'est passé plusieurs fois. Au lieu de parler de la première fois on parle d'une autre fois, en la désignant par ce qu'il s'est passé.

Comment: Pour la première, je remplacerais "où" par "dans lequel".

Comment: @m.raynal - ce _où_ me semble acceptable aussi. Je ne sens pas qu'il serait moins préférable que _dans lequel_, ou alors la différence est faible pour moi.

Comment: merci. qu'est-ce que "la construction assez proche"?